# Hazelcast memory allocation among maps and class-loading memory

Tags: memory, classloader, allocation, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast and are primarily using Maps for caching.  We are distributing the total memory available on the service among various maps.  So for example if we have 1GB memory available...we are allocating 500MB each to 2 of our maps.  My question is should be not fully allocate whats available?  Should we instead leave some of the memory unallocated so that Hazelcast classes can consume some of the memory and if so what would be a good number for unallocated memory.

Just to be clear everything is functional with what we have....but I was not sure what was the best practice...may be for better performance.

Comment: What do you mean with 'fully allocate whats available'. 

And can you be a bit more precise with your questions, because I have a hard time understanding what the question is.

Comment: Remember to divide available memory by `backup_count+1`. So if you have backup_count = 1 then there will be 2 allocations per object on that server (1 for the primary, 1 for the backup)